# How to use 2 models in 1 view django?

Tags: django, django-models

So I have a model

```
class Question(models.Model):
question = models.CharField(max_length=255)
body = models.TextField()
author = models.ForeignKey(
    get_user_model(), 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
)

def __str__(self):
    return self.question

def check_answer(self, choice):
    return self.choice_set.filter(id=choice.id, is_answer=True).exists()

def get_answers(self):
    return self.choice_set.filter(is_answer=True)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('article_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

and another model

```
class Choice(models.Model):
question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='choices', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
is_answer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
def __str__(self):
    return self.choice_text
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('article_list')
```

How can I display both of these in the same view OR is there a better way of doing this

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me *what* you want to display in the view. What will the view display? A single `Question` and all the `Choice`s? Do you already have a view where you display the `Question`?

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:**

You can directly use Question and Chioce in your template. Take DetailView as an example:

```
class QuestionView(DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = "question/question_list.html"
```

and in your template:

```
<h2>Questions</h2>
<div>
    <div>{{ object.body }} <br></div>
    <ul>
        {% for choice in object.choices.all %}
            <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Solution 2:**

Override get_context_data(**kwargs):

```
class QuestionView(DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = "question/question_list.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.object:
            context['choices'] = self.objects.chioces.all()
        return context
```